# Compute maxima and minima of a 4D tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Suppose that we have a 4-dimensional tensor, for instance

```
import torch
X = torch.rand(2, 3, 4, 4)                                                                                                                                                                
tensor([[[[-0.9951,  1.6668,  1.3140,  1.4274],
          [ 0.2614,  2.6442, -0.3041,  0.7337],
          [-1.2690,  0.0125, -0.3885,  0.0535],
          [ 1.5270, -0.1186, -0.4458,  0.1389]],

         [[ 0.9125, -1.2998, -0.4277, -0.2688],
          [-1.6917, -0.8855, -0.2784, -0.6717],
          [ 1.1417,  0.4574,  0.4803, -1.6637],
          [ 0.7322,  0.2654, -0.1525,  1.7285]],

         [[ 1.8310, -1.5765,  0.1392,  1.3431],
          [-0.6641, -1.5090, -0.4893, -1.4110],
          [ 0.5875,  0.7528, -0.6482, -0.2547],
          [-2.3133,  0.3888,  2.1428,  0.2331]]]])
```

I want to compute the maximum and the minimum values of `X` over the dimensions 2 and 3, that is, to compute two tensors of size (2,3,1,1), one for the maximum and one for the minimum values of the 4x4 blocks.

I started by trying to do that with `torch.max()` and `torch.min()`, but I had no luck. I would expect the `dim` argument of the above functions to be able to take tuple values, but it can take only an integer. So I don't know how to proceed.

However, specifically for the maximum values, I decided to use `torch.nn.MaxPool2d()` with `kernel_size=4` and `stride=4`. This indeed did the job:

```
max_pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=4, stride=4)
X_max = max_pool(X)                                                                                                                                                                  
tensor([[[[2.6442]],
         [[1.7285]],
         [[2.1428]]]])
```

But, afaik, there's no similar layer for "min"-pooling. Could you please help me on how to compute the minima similarly to the maxima?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate the max for both dimensions sequentially, it gives the same result:

```
tup = (2,3)
for dim in tup:
    X = torch.max(X,dim=dim,keepdim=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use torch>=1.11, please use torch.amax function,

```
dim = (2,3)
x     = torch.rand(2,3,4,4)
x_max = torch.amax(x,dim=dim)
```

However, if you use the older version of Pytorch, then please use this custom max function

```
def torch_max(x,dim):
    s1 = [i for i in range(len(x.shape)) if i not in dim] 
    s2 = [i for i in range(len(x.shape)) if i in dim]
    x2 = x.permute(tuple(s1+s2))
    s = [d for (i,d) in enumerate(x.shape) if i not in dim] + [-1]
    x2 = torch.reshape(x2, tuple(s))
    max,_ = x2.max(-1)
    return max
```

Usage of this function is very similar to the original torch.max function.

```
dim = (2,3)
x     = torch.rand(2,3,4,4)
x_max = torch_max(x,dim=dim)
```

If the length of `dim` is long, then this custom `torch_max` is slightly faster.